# Powershell System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 issues

Tags: powershell, x509certificate

i can get the code to work but im having issues when i try to narrow down my choices. I'm using powershell 7.3.

This code works fine for what i need here:

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security

```
$ValidCerts = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2[]](Get-ChildItem 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My')
$Cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2UI]::SelectFromCollection($ValidCerts, 'Choose a certificate', 'Choose a certificate', 0)

$Pin = Read-Host "Enter your PIN: " -AsSecureString
$Script:cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Cert,$Pin
```

===========================================================================

This code here doesnt work at all:

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security

```
$ValidCerts = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2[]](Get-ChildItem 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My') | ?{$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -like 'Client Authentication'}
$Cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2UI]::SelectFromCollection($ValidCerts, 'Choose a certificate', 'Choose a certificate', 0)

$Pin = Read-Host "Enter your PIN: " -AsSecureString
$Script:cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Cert,$Pin
```

error that I'm getting:

MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "SelectFromCollection" and the argument count: "4".

If i could get an answer to this that would be nice but i can use the top code just fine

Comment: I wonder about your way of using -like without wildcards. Isnt that basicly the same thing like using -eq?

Comment: yes there the same in this instance.

Comment: ```SelectFromCollection``` takes a ```X509Certificate2Collection ``` as the first parameter - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui.selectfromcollection?view=windowsdesktop-7.0. In your second example you’re trying to pass an *array* of ```X509Certificate2``` but there’s no overload that accepts it as the first parameter.

Comment: What I think you need to do is construct a new ```X509Certificate2Collection``` from your filtered results and pass *that* to ```SelectFromCollection``` instead - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate2collection-ctor(system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate2())

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge i will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments, the [SelectFromCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui.selectfromcollection?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) method takes a **X509Certificate2Collection** as the first parameter. In in your second example you’re trying to pass an array of **X509Certificate2** but there’s no overload that accepts it as the first parameter.

What you need to do is construct a new **X509Certificate2Collection** from your filtered results and pass that to **SelectFromCollection** instead - see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate2collection-ctor(system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate2())) for an example.

If you modify your second example like this it will work:

```
# get a filtered list of certificates to select from
$ValidCerts = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2[]] (
    Get-ChildItem "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
) | where-object {
    $_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -like "Client Authentication"
};

# convert the array of X509Certificate2s into a X509Certificate2Collection
$collection = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection(
    @(, $ValidCerts)
);

# pass the X509Certificate2Collection to SelectFromCollection instead
$Cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2UI]::SelectFromCollection(
    $collection, # <-- X509Certificate2Collection 
    "Choose a certificate",
    "Choose a certificate",
    0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the parentheses to the end of your filter:

```
$ValidCerts = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2[]](Get-ChildItem  Cert:\CurrentUser\My | ?{$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -like 'Client Authentication'})
```